# ACS Evaluation for a Company who has stopped working

Tags: working-visas, australia

So I was working on a Consulting capacity 8 years ago with a company who have closed their operations recently. Since this experience is vital for me to claim that 1 years of experience for my 5 extra points, can someone let me know what I could do show that experience in the ACS evaluation? I don't know anyone who was working with me since I was the only one representing them. Can anyone let me know what could be my further options?

Comment: Would e.g. your employment contract count? Did you not have a boss you could contact? Search people on Linkedin?

Answer (score 1):

[ACS Skill Assessment](https://www.acs.org.au/content/dam/acs/acs-skills/Skills%20Assessment%20Guidelines%20for%20Applicants%20-%20July%202017.pdf) recognizes that there may be circumstances in which applicants are unable to obtain the necessary information directly. In that case, the applicant can make a Statutory Declaration; see page 12, Section 11. STATUTORY DECLARATIONS AND AFFIDAVITS.

A better understanding may be had from an earlier ACS document, [Pre-Application Skills Assessment (PASA) Guidelines for Applicants](https://www.scribd.com/document/176491636/PASAGuidelinesforApplicants-July2011v2-0-1):

> 1.2. Where past education providers and/or employers no longer exist and you need this information for your application, you may submit a personal statement on a properly signed and witnessed Statutory Declaration. The Statutory Declaration is to detail as a minimum:
>
> § the reason/s why you are submitting a Statutory Declaration; and
>
> § all the necessary detail about your education and/or employment.
>
> Important: If you provide a Statutory Declaration with your application, you must also provide some form of corroborative information from a third party for the claims made in the Statutory Declaration.